# HTTP 503 error when trying to create a S3 snaphost repo for ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, amazon-s3, snapshot, connection-timeout

I get a HTTP 503 error whenever I try to [create a repository for an Elasticsearch snapshot on an Amazon S3 bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.4/repository-s3-usage.html):

```
[root@myserver ~]# curl -XPUT 'https://myes.example.org:9200/_snapshot/s3_repository' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": { "bucket": "mybucket/elk" }
}'
```

After 30 seconds, it times out:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"process_cluster_event_timeout_exception","reason":"failed to process cluster event (put_repository [s3_repository]) within 30s"}],"type":"process_cluster_event_timeout_exception","reason":"failed to process cluster event (put_repository [s3_repository]) within 30s"},"status":503}
```

However, the S3 bucket is indeed reachable from my server:

```
[root@myserver ~]# aws s3 cp testfile s3://mybucket/elk/ --sse AES256

upload: ./testfile to s3://mybucket/elk/testfile
```

What could be the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, did you install the `S3 Repository Plugin` ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.4/repository-s3.html

Also, are you running the curl command from an EC2 instance or AWS ECS ? Because, by default the repository defaults to using ECS IAM Role or EC2 IAM Role credentials for authentication. If you are not using EC2 or AWS ECS please specify the credentials which has access to that bucket in S3 or see my answer below to easily register from Kibana Dev Tools

Comment: Yes, I installed the S3 Repository plugin and restarted the node.  I am running this from an AWS instance with IAM permissions set -- in fact, I am able to upload files from command line, so it doesn't look like a permission problem.

Comment: Well aws cli will still work if you have a default profile configured irrespective of whether you are running it from an AWS EC2 instance with an IAM role or not ;) Glad to hear that this is working for you now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a transient error, as now it works.

By the way, it was also necessary to specify the `base_path` setting in the JSON:

```
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": { "bucket": "mybucket",  "base_path": "elk"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the credentails are stored in keystore properly.

```
cat /aws/access_key | base64 --decode | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin --force s3.client.default.access_key && \
cat /aws/secret_key | base64 --decode | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin --force s3.client.default.secret_key
```

***From the plugin documentation:***

**S3 Repository Plugin**

The S3 repository plugin adds support for using S3 as a repository for {ref}/modules-snapshots.html[Snapshot/Restore].

If you are looking for a hosted solution of Elasticsearch on AWS, please visit http://www.elastic.co/cloud.

**Getting started with AWS**

The plugin provides a repository type named s3 which may be used when creating a repository. The repository defaults to using ECS IAM Role or EC2 IAM Role credentials for authentication. The only mandatory setting is the bucket name:

```
PUT _snapshot/my_s3_repository
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "my_bucket"
  }
}
```

Client Settings

The client used to connect to S3 has a number of settings available. Client setting names are of the form s3.client.CLIENT_NAME.SETTING_NAME. The default client name, which is looked up by an s3 repository, is called default. It can be modified using the repository setting client. For example:

```
PUT _snapshot/my_s3_repository
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "my_bucket",
    "client": "my_alternate_client"
  }
}
```

Most client settings are specified inside elasticsearch.yml, but some are sensitive and must be stored in the {ref}/secure-settings.html[elasticsearch keystore].

For example, before you start the node, run these commands to add AWS access key settings to the keystore:

```
bin/elasticsearch-keystore add s3.client.default.access_key
bin/elasticsearch-keystore add s3.client.default.secret_key
```

All client secure settings of this plugin are {ref}/secure-settings.html#reloadable-secure-settings[reloadable]. After you reload the settings, the internal s3 clients, used to transfer the snapshot contents, will utilize the latest settings from the keystore. Any existing s3 repositories, as well as any newly created ones, will pick up the new values stored in the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can run the below from Kibana Dev Tools to easily register s3 snapshot repository.

```
PUT _snapshot/s3_repository
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "<s3-bucket-name>",
    "region": "<region_name>",
    "access_key": "<access_key>",
    "secret_key": "<secret_key>",
    "compress": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, we don't use an access/secret key, we use IAM permissions.  It is probably a problem with the policies.

Comment: this is an insecure option